# c/c++: thread to decrement a variable every 1 second? (in windows)

Tags: windows, multithreading, posix

Well, I was planning to do this:

```
 int seconds = 90;

void *DecreaseSeconds(){

    while (seconds>-1) 
       {
          seconds--;
          sleep(1000);   
       }

       return NULL;
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        int threadid= pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, DecreaseSeconds, NULL);
        pthread_join(threadid, NULL);

    }
```

Yet I get this dreadful thing  when I try to compile on Visual Studio 2008

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory
```

I want a way to translate this to windows or make Visual Studio accept my posix thread.

Comment: you're in luck, the windows threading model is much richer than posix!

Comment: and there's always timers which would avoid the need for a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Look up RTL function _beginthreadex.

Answer (score 1):

There is no POSIX thread support on Win32. You need to use Win32 threads or an abstraction that supports both.